# Validating form with files

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with input=file. I'd like to validate in with javascript/jquery and check if the file field is filled. How can I do this ?

Comment: By checking its value (`.val()` in jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my-form-id').submit(function(ev) {
    if (!$('#my-file-input-id').val()) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      alert('Please select a file to upload.');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('#idofinputfield').val()) {
    alert('please select a file');
}
```